# SQL finding multiple instances of records in 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to find one instance to report on from ONE table that holds multiple transactions per ID. I want to only get the records back that had  Transaction numbers that have both (ABCD) and (XYZ), Meaning I should get back the records with ID's (123, 456).

The table data looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<table>
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Transaction Number</th><th>Trans Date</th></tr>
<tr><td>123 </td><td>ABCD </td><td>1/1/2001 </td></tr>
<tr><td> 123</td><td>XYZ </td><td> 1/1/2001</td></tr>
<tr><td>456 </td><td>ABCD </td><td>1/1/2001 </td></tr>
<tr><td>456 </td><td>XYZ </td><td>1/1/2001 </td></tr>
<tr><td>7896 </td><td>ABCD </td><td>1/1/2001 </td></tr>
<tr><td> 7896</td><td>ABCD </td><td> 1/1/2001</td></tr>
</table>
</HTML>
```

Im trying to figure out what the SQL Query would look like for this problem.

Comment: Do you mean duplicates?

Comment: No I want the record that has a combination of Transaction Numbers of (ABCD) and (XYZ). SO if I searched by those transaction numbers in the query, it would return records with (123, 456) and exclude the record with ID 7896.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your MySQL table looks like this...

```
   id  trans
 ----  ------
  123  ABCD
  123  XYZ 
  456  ABCD
  456  XYZ
 7896  ABCD
 7896  ABCD
```

Several approaches to getting the specified result. One is to use an EXISTS predicate

```
SELECT t.id
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.trans = 'ABCD'
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                  FROM mytable s
                 WHERE s.id = t.id
                   AND s.trans = 'XYZ'
              )
```

Another approach is to use a GROUP BY and a COUNT DISTINCT

```
SELECT t.id
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.trans IN ('XYZ','ABCD')
GROUP BY t.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.trans) > 1
```

Comment: This returned a record with ID 7896 that should have been excluded

Comment: Here's a SQL Fiddle demonstration [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a87b84/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a87b84/1) which shows that both of the provided queries return the specified result (excluding id 7896.) If neither of those queries is working for you, there's something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you want to get the smalest *id* in data which meets your needs:

```
SELECT MIN(A.id)
FROM (
    SELECT t.id
    FROM mytable t
    WHERE t.trans IN ('XYZ','ABCD')
    GROUP BY t.id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.trans) > 1
) AS A
```